# Windows Phone Library projects

Tags: dll, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, static-libraries

I am complete newbie to the windows phone development and just starting to write a module that i hope to deploy as library project that could be referenced from with in a windows mobile application and could access the UI components etc. I have been looking to find a way to do that but no luck so far. Basically what i am looking for is an alternate of a an android library project or a jar file for windows phone apps. I'd really appreciate an informed opinion about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a library project, when creating the new project select the Windows Phone Library project template:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @anderZubi. That seems good but i wouldn't want to keep it open source. Can i export that library project as a closed source library ?

Comment: When you build the project you will get a compiled .dll file in the /bin directory